# FragmentPagerAdapter is deprecated problem

Tags: java, android-studio, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

Android Studio says fragment pager adapter is deprecated.
How can I remove this error? [here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPedx.png)

```
public static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;
    private ArrayList<String> titles;
    
    public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The **FragmentPagerAdapter** class in Android is indeed deprecated as of AndroidX library version **1.2.0**. It is recommended to use **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** or **FragmentPagerAdapter2** instead.

1. Replace **FragmentPagerAdapter** with **FragmentStatePagerAdapter**:

   public static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
2. Update the constructor of ViewPagerAdapter to call the appropriate
   superclass constructor:

   public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
   super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
   }

These changes will ensure that you are using the recommended replacement for **FragmentPagerAdapter** and resolve the deprecation problem.

Comment: It says "FragmentStatePagerAdapter is deprecated" too.
What should I do?

Comment: Md. Kabir Hassan - Welcome back to Stack Overflow. It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since most or all seven of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.